# listenTo not working when using in another view in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I am a newbee to backbone.I have a view called AbcView
abc.js

```
var AbcView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "click" : "display",
    },
    display: function(e){
        console.log("hello");
        alert("click function");
    }
});
```

Now I am passing this abc.js to another xyz.js file and calling it in another view using ListenTo.

`xyz.js`

```
var xyzView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        var AbcView = new AbcView ();
        this.lisenTo(AbcView, "click",this.display);
    },
    render: function(){
        var html = this.template(AbcView);
        this.$el.html(html);
        return this;
    },
    display: function(e){
        console.log("parent hello");
        alert("parent display function");
    }
});
```

With abc.js click event is triggering fine. But with xyz.js click event is not triggering.

Is this the correct way to call listenTo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DOM events aren't delegated on the View object.

If you want to emulate this though, you'd have to manually emit the event in ABC `display` method:

```
display: function(e){

    // Trigger manually
    this.trigger("click");

    // Your usual code
    console.log("hello");
    alert("click function");
}
```

In term of best practice, I'd probably rename "click" to a more descriptive event name.

Answer (score 3):

Backbone's `on` and `listenTo` are intended for listening to events on Backbone `Models` and `Collections`.

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

This is an important thing to understand. It is not the same as UI event binding, as described in http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents.

That being said, you can use something like what Simon suggests to intermingle the two.